# DomPdf - Fixed header in all pages but it collapse with a table

Tags: php, css, laravel, dompdf

I'm a student learning php and pdfs.

I'm having a problem with dom pdf, i printing a table that it have to be on 3 pages of a pdf. First I create a header with the logo and some titles. It header has to be on all the pages, i created it Fixed position, but on the second and the third page the table go on middle of the header.

[image]

The problem is this, I had to censore the letter but you see the problem perfect. I don't have any idea how to solve it. : 
[image: php]

Css code

```
   header {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0cm;
            left: 0cm;
            right: 0cm;
            height: 3cm;
        }
```

Comment: we need your code amigo!

Comment: @delboy1978uk is not a code problem, is a style problem, that i dont know how to do this

Comment: your style is also code

Comment: @delboy1978uk i added my css code of the header

Comment: have you tried relative instead of fixed? also, try `clear: both` on the table once you try with relative positioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the example of footer and header html: https://gist.github.com/doobas/d5ba90c73f5d8d6c229e1a7855f7355a

You have to add margin for body.

Comment: Broken link here!!!